# Insert data into database using JSP

Tags: mysql, jsp

I have displayed data from a database table and in each row i have put check box and here user will check products and at the end of the press of save button whereas data should be inserted to another table in database using JSP.

How can i do this?

My JSP code:

```
<% 
pds=new Products();
for(int i=0;i<listpds.size();i++){

pds=(Products)listpds.get(i);
%>

<TR>

<TD><%=pds.getP_id()%></TD>
<TD><%=pds.getP_name()%></TD>
<TD><%=pds.getP_details()%></TD>
<TD><%=pds.getP_price()%></TD>


<TD><input type="checkbox" name="product" value="Bike"> Select </TD>
</TR>

<% } %>
```

Comment: Please provide details on what exactly doesn't work with your current approach, e.g. an error message.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer using ORM frameworks such as spring data, hibernate, etc. I sharing primitive technique for starting point below:

```
import java.util.List;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;

DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost/mydb?useConfigs=maxPerformance&characterEncoding=utf8&useSSL=false");
dataSource.setUsername("root");
dataSource.setPassword("pass");
JdbcTemplate jdbc = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource)
jdbc.execute("INSERT INTO mytable (field1, field2) VALUES ('stringvalue',integervalue)");
```